# How to know constraints,indexes,sequences without reading data dictionary?

Tags: oracle9i

I want to show indexes,sequences,constraints in DESC command ,is it possible,
or any other cammand by which i can see structure(design) of a table along with constraints,
sequences,indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL()` (or it could be `FETCH_DDL()`, I don't have 9i documentation online) command can show you everything.